# Python: Add a column to list of lists with values supplied by a third list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists that is generated by a function and can have anywhere between 0 and 300 name pairs, with data like this:

```
sales reps = [('David', 'Anderson'), ('Darla', 'Becker'), ('Charlie', 'Davis')]
```

I also have a list called `regions`.

```
regions = ['Pacific', 'Midwest', 'East', 'Northwest', ...]
```

I want to add a third column to `sales_reps` that assigns a `region` to it by iterating through `regions` so that I end up with:

```
sales reps_new = [('David', 'Anderson', 'Pacific'), ('Darla', 'Becker', 'Midwest'), ('Charlie', 'Davis', 'East')]
```

I have tried `zip()`, but that cuts off the list at the end of regions such that if sales_reps has 30 entries and regions has 4, `zip` will only give me 4.

Comment: Did you try to do this yourself?

Comment: have you tried using a simple for loop using count.

Comment: zip stops at the end of the shorter list, so it already stops where you want. If you wanted to go to the longer length you have to do something extra, like use  zip_longest from itertools.  You just need to unpack and regenerate the tuples you get from zip().

Answer (score -1):

Since these are more object-oriented concepts, where a Sales Rep can be modeled by their first and last names along with a region assignment, it makes sense to break things up and give them an elementary class.

```py
sales_reps = [('David', 'Anderson'), ('Darla', 'Becker'), ('Charlie', 'Davis')]
regions = ['Pacific', 'Midwest', 'East', 'Northwest']

class SalesRep:
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.first_name = first
        self.last_name = last
        self.region = None

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.last_name}, {self.first_name}\t{self.region}"


people = []
for rep in sales_reps:
    people.append(SalesRep(first=rep[0], last=rep[1]))

for region in regions:
    for person in people:
        if not person.region:
            person.region = region
            break

for person in people:
    print(person)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following code :

```
regionsCount = len(regions)
j=0
temp_list = list()
for i in sales_reps:
   if j>=regionsCount:
       j=0
   temp = list(i)
   temp.append(regions[j])
   temp_list.append(tuple(temp))
   j = j+1

sales_reps = temp_list
```

Above code will repeat the regions if they are less than sales_reps list.